# How can I generate stairs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    public int delay = 3;
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public int stairsHeight = 0;
    public Vector3 stairsPosition;
    public Vector2 stairsSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i <= stairsSize.x; i++)
        {
            for (float k = 0; k <= stairsSize.y; k++)
            {
                stairsPosition = new Vector3(i, stairsHeight, k);
                GameObject stairs = Instantiate(stairsPrefab, stairsPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                stairs.transform.localScale = new Vector3(stairsSize.x, 1 , stairsSize.y);

                stairsHeight += 1;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CalculateNextStair()
    {

    }
}
```

I messed it up. For example I want to build 5 stairs but the loops are over the stairs size and not number of stairs.

Second it's creating 10 sets of stairs not 5 stairs:

[image: stairs]

Another problem is how can I make that each stair will be build slowly ? Now it's just Instantiate slowly with delay but how can I generate each stair with delay?

Screenshot of the script inspector:

[image: Inspector]

My current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    public float delay = 0.3f;
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public int stairsPositions = 0;
    public int stairsStartPositionHeight = 0;
    public float stairsScalingHaight = 1;
    public Vector2 stairsPosition;
    public Vector2 stairsSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i <= stairsNumber; i++)
        {
            // x=0f, y=z=stairsHeight
            stairsPosition = new Vector3(0f, stairsPositions, stairsPositions);
            GameObject stairs = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);
            stairs.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                    stairsSize.x,
                    stairsScalingHaight,
                    stairsSize.y);

            stairsStartPositionHeight += 1;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }

    private void CalculateNextStair()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your script inspector on Unity? I'd like to reproduce the situation.

Comment: @VitorFigueredo Added it to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to loop over the size of the stairs at all; you want to loop over `stairsNumber`, which is yet unused in your code.

Also, you don't need to change the `x` component of your stairs' positions. Keep it at `0f` (or whatever you need).

The `y` and `z` components of your stairs positions (relative to the starting point) should both be factors of `stairHeight`. In this particular case, you want them to be equal to `stairHeight`, so that you get "square" step shapes.

```
private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= stairsNumber ; i++) {
        // x=0f, y=z=stairsHeight
        stairsPosition = new Vector3(0f, stairsHeight, stairsHeight);
        GameObject stairs = Instantiate(
                stairsPrefab, 
                stairsPosition, 
                Quaternion.identity);
        stairs.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                stairsSize.x, 
                1f , 
                stairsSize.y);

        stairsHeight += 1f;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

If you change `stairSize` to be a `Vector3`, then you can just use `stairSize` directly as the `localScale`, and increment `stairsHeight` by `stairsSize.y` instead of just `1f`.

If you want to offset the starting position of your stairs, you need to include an offset. I recommend keeping it separate from the height counter until you need to add them.

Also, if you want to have rectangular sized steps, keep a `widthFactor` to multiply by the height to find how far each step moves horizontally.

Combining these changes might look like this:

```
Vector3 stairSize;
float stepWidthFactor=1f;
Vector3 stairsStartPosition;

private IEnumerator BuildStairs() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= stairsNumber ; i++) {

        stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                stairsStartPosition.x, 
                stairsStartPosition.y + stairsHeight,
                stairsStartPosition.z + stairsHeight*stepWidthFactor);

        GameObject stairs = Instantiate(
                stairsPrefab, 
                stairsPosition, 
                Quaternion.identity);

        stairsHeight += stairsSize.y;
        stairs.transform.localScale = stairSize;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Working great. I tried now for some minutes to use also the position x now it's set to 0f and also the scale is now set to 1f. What if I want to create bigger stairs on the height scale ? And if I want to move the stairs on also z position ? And this: stairsStartPositionHeight += 1; if I want to start the stairs in the sky ? It's all working but too many variables and almost same names.

Comment: have updated my question with my code now. Seems to be a bit messed. I think this variable stairsStartPositionHeight and this stairsScalingHaight variable should be part of the vectors. Instead vector2 to change it to vector3 but not sure how to make the code to work with vector3 for position and scaling.

Comment: @DubiDuboni I edited my answer to include how you could start your stairs from a different position, as well as have different step lengths compared to their height.

Comment: Some question please. The Step Width Factor if for testing I change it to 20 it will change the angle of the steps but also will make big gaps/spaces between each stair. It should make this gaps or the factor is for changing the angle ?

Comment: If you don't want gaps, you need to change `stairSize.z` to be larger. When `stairSize.z < stairSize.y * stepWidthFactor` then there are gaps.

Comment: One last question: What is the different between Stairs Height and the Stairs Start Position ? If I change one of them for example to 200 it will start building the stairs from this height. Do I need then also the Stairs Height ?

Comment: `stairsHeight` is different than `stairsStartPosition`. `stairsHeight` keeps track of how high the last stair you've made so far is. They are only equal for the `0` step. You could get rid of `stairsHeight += stairsSize.y;` and replace every remaining mention of `stairsHeight` with `(i * stairsSize.y)` and that would still work.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much for the help.